# Escape grep in a script

Tags: grep, escaping

I want to create a script with cat EOL but when I paste the code in terminal will hang wit error: cat: -: Input/output error.
I want just the paste content of the script not to execute grep commands. This line gives me issues

```
cat >> /etc/script << EOF
....
if [ -z "`ps axf | grep \${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
...
EOF
```

Comment: I couldn't find a better duplicate, this one is extremely wordy - the point is: use `'EOF'` instead of `EOF`.

Comment: Excelent answer, this solved my issue, and I don't need to escape other \$ anymore.